# Match any tags in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a simple function that assigns a category to a post (using save_post) IF the post has ANY matching terms. The problem is that while it works with ONE term, trying to match multiple terms is not working. This works:

```
function categorize_from_tags( $post_id ) {

    $cat_boosted = 'cat-boosted';
    $terms = 'twin-turbo';

    if( has_term( $terms, 'post_tag' ) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_boosted, 'category', true );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'categorize_from_tags', 120, 1 );
```

When I add multiple terms, it does NOT work:

```
function categorize_from_tags( $post_id ) {

    $cat_boosted = 'cat-boosted';
    $terms = 'twin-turbo,ugr'; // Adding more than one term

    if( has_term( $terms, 'post_tag' ) ) {
        wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_boosted, 'category', true );
    }

}
add_action( 'save_post', 'categorize_from_tags', 120, 1 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are sending in a category name of 'twin-turbo,ugr'.

You want to send in an array like so:

```
$terms = ['twin-turbo','ugr'];
```

Make sure you check the parameters of the WP Global function you are trying to use.

has_term accepts a string or an array of strings to match against.